# Is it possible to get permission to fly in the DCA “no drone” area?

Tags: faa-regulations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

The entire immediate Washington D.C. area is in a “no drone zone”, in a 15 mile radius from DCA.

Are there ways to get an exemption for activities such as film making, property inspections, etc?

Answer (score 14):

Yes. [This page](https://www.faa.gov/uas/resources/community_engagement/no_drone_zone/dc/) comes up on a quick Google search.

> Flying an unmanned aircraft within the 15-mile radius inner ring is prohibited without specific FAA authorization.

> Experienced Part 107 and public aircraft operators with justification can file your request through the on-line Access Program (AAP) https://waivers.faa.gov